# Plugin does not work in custom theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

I created a new theme, starting by zero. The theme works correctly, but some plugins not.

I installed ***Google Analytics & Webmaster Tools***, I compiled the plugin with my track codes, but in the html code them did non appear.

Comment: does your theme call `wp_head` and `wp_footer` in the template?

Comment: Yes (its a WP Multisite)

Comment: @Milo, I did misunderstood. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

By the sounds of it, your custom theme is missing the common hooks that allow plugins to alter/output their code.

To take a simple example, every theme should have a call to wp_head() somewhere in the  section of the output page. This allows a plugin to "hook" into your , and for example, output code to load its Javascript.

Here's a real-life example. The WordPress Twentyfifteen theme has this in its header.php file (traditionally the part of a theme that outputs the  section of any page):

```
... other <head> stuff
    wp_head();
    wp_footer();

?>  
</head>
```

Comment: You should mention `wp_footer()`

Comment: `wp_footer` goes in the footer, not the head, it should be the last thing before the closing body tag